# Web hosting error (Cent os )

Tags: web-hosting, self-hosting

When I host my site on cent OS web panel and unzip my content into my server directory along with database and make proper changes in configuration file but when I browse my site it shows a blank page.

> fatal error: call to a member function isEnalbled() on a non object in
>   /home/wnp/public_html/libraries/gantry/core/gantry.class.php

Comment: Can you explain "along with database" what does that mean ?

Comment: The error is incomplete, it should show something more like "call to a member function isEnabled() on a non-object ....", please always include full error messages and don't cut them off as that could remove crucial information. Either way, this error indicates there is a problem inside the code that means that either not all depencies have been installed or an error has been made by the developer.

Comment: fatal error: call to a member function isEnalbled() on a non object in /home/wnp/public_html/libraries/gantry/core/gantry.class.php

Comment: this site is running on my old server but when i transfer it to new server its showing me a blank page